# Redshift datediff() vs. date_diff()

Tags: amazon-redshift

It appears that Redshift supports two possible functions for computing a time interval distance between two `DATE`-like objects: `DATEDIFF()` & `date_diff()`. The following code snippet provides an example of this behavior:

```
SELECT datediff(DAYS,   '2021-01-01'::DATE, '2021-02-01'::DATE) AS datediff_interval_output
     , datediff('day',  '2021-01-01'::DATE, '2021-02-01'::DATE) AS datediff_str_literal_output
     , date_diff('day', '2021-01-01'::DATE, '2021-02-01'::DATE) AS date_diff_output
;
```

AWS provides documentation on [DATEDIFF()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATEDIFF_function.html), however no record of `date_diff()` appears to exist within either Redshift or PostgreSQL documentation. A curious difference between the two functions is that `DATEDIFF` will accept either a raw interval for its first argument (e.g. `DAY`, `MONTH`, `SECOND`) or a string literal (*'day'*, *'month'*, *'second*'), but `date_diff()` only accepts string literal interval representations.

The only reference I can find to `date_diff()` is an entry within *pg_catalog* which returns the following auto-generated definition:

```
CREATE FUNCTION date_diff(text, time with time zone, time with time zone) RETURNS bigint
    IMMUTABLE
    LANGUAGE internal AS
$$
begin
-- missing source code
end;
$$;
```

Does anyone have additional insight around the origin of the `date_diff()` function, and why it's included on Redshift but is undocumented?

---

<sub>**Note:** Using Redshift Version: 1.0.25109</sub>

Comment: Are you sure that date_diff() isn't a UDF someone put on your cluster?

Comment: I am fairly certain that this isn't a UDF, since it exists within the *pg_catalog* schema, and is defined using the language *internal*, both of which cannot happen from a UDF. I just attempted to run a `CREATE FUNCTION` command using language *internal* within the *public* schema and received an error: *ERROR: Create function is not supported for language internal.*. When I attempt to execute a `CREATE FUNCTION` command against *pg_catalog*, I receive a different error: *ERROR:  permission denied for schema pg_catalog*. Both of these commands were executed using the cluster's root/admin user.

Comment: datediff() is the built in POSTGRES function.  as your code shows date_diff() is a defined function (CREATE FUNCTION ...) and this definition has "text" as the type of the first argument.  So you need to pass text in the first position or you will get this error.  Your question is about origin and I don't believe this function existed 4-5 years back.  I suspect it was introduced with timestamps with timezone b/c Postgres 8 didn't have timezone datediff().  So this way a way to get timezones w/o reworking the base function which they now have done.  An artifact of days gone by.